# Auto Update Properties file value in Java project

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, properties-file, hotdeploy

I have java application hosted on apache tomcat. There are some values derived from project.properties file. But to reflect any new/changed property value, i need to restart tomcat service/application service.

So is there any way to reflect these changes on run-time / on-fly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad and does not specify if you're using a specific framework for building your application. Most frameworks have some default support for this, so if you building a plain Java application running in Tomcat you can do this by making use of for instance 'commons configuration'.

With 'commons configuration' you can setup a properties configuration with a reloading strategy:

```
String filePath = "/some/path/project.properties";
configuration = new PropertiesConfiguration(filePath);

FileChangedReloadingStrategy fileChangedReloadingStrategy = new FileChangedReloadingStrategy();
// 1 second refresh
fileChangedReloadingStrategy.setRefreshDelay("1000");
configuration.setReloadingStrategy(fileChangedReloadingStrategy);
```

A complete worked out example with Spring can be found in [this tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/reloadedable-properties-file-spring-using-apache-commons-configuration/).

Comment: I the above works please mark this answer as a correct answer for this question.